# Heavy disk io write in select statement in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hadoop-yarn

In hive I running a query -

```sql
select ret[0],ret[1],ret[2],ret[3],ret[4],ret[5],ret[6] from (select combined1(extra) as ret from log_test1) a ;
```

Here `ret[0]`,`ret[1]`,`ret[2]` `...` are domain, date, IP, etc. This query is doing heavy write on disk.

`iostat` result on one of the box in cluster.

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          20.65    0.00    1.82   57.14    0.00   20.39
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00  535.00     0.00 23428.00    87.58   143.94  269.11    0.00  269.11   1.87 100.00
```

My mapper is basically stuck in disk IO.  I have 3 box cluster. My `yarn` configuration is

```
Mapper memory(mapreduce.map.memory.mb)=2GB, 
I/O Sort Memory Buffer=1 GB. 
I/O Sort Spill Percent=0.8
```

Counters of my jobs are

```
FILE: Number of bytes read  0 
FILE: Number of bytes written   2568435 
HDFS: Number of bytes read  1359720216 
HDFS: Number of bytes written   19057298627 

Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot     24351916032 
Total committed heap usage (bytes)  728760320 
Physical memory (bytes) snapshot    2039455744 
Map input records   76076426 
Input split bytes   2738 
GC time elapsed (ms)    55602 
Spilled Records     0
```

As mapper should initially write everything in RAM and when RAM gets full(I/O Sort Memory Buffer),it should spill the data into disk. But as I am seeing, `Spilled Records=0` and also mapper is not using full RAM, still there is so heavy disk write.

Even when I am running query

```
select combined1(extra) from log_test1;
```

I am getting same heavy disk io write.

What can be the reason of this heavy disk write and how can I reduce this heavy disk write ? As in this case disk io is becoming bottleneck for my mapper.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your subquery is being written to disk before the second stage of the processing takes place. You should use `Explain` to examine the execution plan.

You could try rewriting your subquery as a CTE https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression

Comment: Even when I am running query (with q1 as (select combined1(extra) as ret from log_test1) from q1 select ret[0],ret[1],ret[2],ret[3],ret[4],ret[5],ret[6];
), disk io writes are same. even when I am running query "select combined1(extra) from log_test1;", I am getting same heavy disk io write.